# TCP/IP unacknowledged data storage

Tags: tcp

we have a windows 2003 server which is accessed from ~100 clients connected through a GB  network and ~400 clients connected outside through a T1 (1.5Mbis/s) line to the internal network. The clients ask the server for data with a size of 300 - 400kB.

The server shows a constant network load of ~1.6Mbis/s and all users have a poor response time.

My assumption is that on packet takes a long time on the T1 line until its acknowledge is received and the "buffer" of the unacknowledged data is full so the local users must wait for a free slot in the buffer.

Is this a possible reason for our problem? And where does this buffer reside (NIC / TCP-Stack / ...)?

Comment: That's not what happens because TCP connections are independent. Investigate to find out why the service is slow. Profile it, or pause it in the debugger a few times to see what it's doing.

Comment: The service is a servlet (MapXtremeJava) running in a TomCat 8. With only "high speed" networks we have no troubles only in this case with most of the client are connected through a very slow network all clients suffer from the bad performance.

Comment: My advice stands: The server or app has a problem. Profile it. Unlikely, that Tomcat 8 cannot serve multiple concurrent clients!